# Deleting large amount of data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have highly unbalanced data (with binary labels, zeros are 96% of data, while ones are just 4%) to balance it I have decided to delete some rows with label zero. However by iterating over the whole dataframe program would take several hours to delete the rows using `pandas.dataframe.drop()` method. What is the most time efficient way to delete the data?

I have tried sorting the data and then just clearing out bunch of rows with label 0, but unfortunately I must not change the order of data.

I have selected indexes of rows with label 0 and chosen random indexes from that list to delete like so:
`drops = random.sample(zero_indexes, X)` (where X is amount of rows I want to delete) but I am not sure how to delete rows with such indexes in acceptable time. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Like `df = df.drop(df.index[df.sum(axis=1) == 0], axis=0)`?

Comment: @CJR but that would delete all the zeros right? I want to delete large amount of zeros at random indexes

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to preserve the order of data, if I just delete bunch of zeros from start, then I would get bunch of ones grouped together, and I dont want that

Comment: That is a poor choice of technique for solving an imbalanced class problem. Also if order is meaningful then you should consider restructuring your data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a list of indices you want to chuck

```
bad_labels = df[df['label'] == 0].sample(500).index
```

Then filter df to rows not in there

```
df1 = df[~df.index.isin(bad_labels)]
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution